# Выдача ромба свежеизбранному модератору

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Недавно закончились вторые в истории ruSO выборы модератора. Многие, наверное, обратили внимание на то, что время на голосование истекло, но результаты на [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2) и странице со [списком модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) появились значительно позже. Хотя в чате [победители уже были обнаружены](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40745915#40745915).

В связи с этим возникает законный вопрос: что должно произойти между окончанием времени голосования и появлением результатов на упомянутых выше страницах, почему это не происходит автоматически сразу после того, как все голоса доступны?

Answer (score 7):

Назначение модераторов происходит вручную. Более того, это могут сделать лишь два человека в нашей команде. Для того, чтобы назначить кого–либо модератором, необходимо написать соответствующему коллеге по почте или в чате.

Comment: Кто эти всемогущие?

Comment: Не знаю, является ли это публичной данными или нет. Вдруг им на почту начнут слать что–нибудь нехорошее!

Comment: почему сразу мысли о негативе? Может наоборот. В любом случае, можно у них спросить, готовы ли они раскрыться и по итогам обновить текущий ответ.

Comment: @alexolut  насколько я понимаю это `Nicolas Chabanovsky` и `Nick V..`. Судя по их профилю они в штате работают

Comment: @alexolut `Nick Volynkin` второй

Comment: @AndrioSkur речь о всей [команде Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team), как я понимаю. Из ruSO сотрудник только один Nicolas Chabanovsky. И говорит он каких-то других двух людях.

Comment: @alexolut Так и есть!